# Hive: What is wrong with this regex?

Tags: regex, hive

I am trying to insert data into a hive table from an input file which is a csv formatted as follows:-

```
stringA,"stringB","stringC",stringD,"stringE","stringF"
```

where stringF has the delimiter ',' within itself.

I tried with the following input regex but i get all NULL values in my table:-

```
create external table tablName(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string, col4 string, col5 string, col6 string)

   row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
("input.regex" =  (([^ ]*),(\"[^\"]\"),(\"[^\"]\"),([^ ]*),(\"[^\"]\"),(\"[^\"]\"))
Location '/path/to/data'
```

Comment: So, to clearify, 1 string without quotes, then 2 with and that repeats, all seperated by comma and you add (but don't show) that the last string will also have a comma withint it that should be matched.

Comment: @QuinnRoundy Yes, exactly.

Comment: are you trying to capture the quotes as well or do they matter?

Comment: (\"[^\"]\"), This needs the change:   (\"[^\"]*\"),

Comment: Aren't there some * missing in col 2, 3, 5,6? The not-" characters are with multiplicity 1 only?

Comment: @QuinnRoundy I am trying to capture it exactly as it is i.e. with the quotes around stringB, stringC, stringE and stringF.

Comment: what type of characters can and cannot be in each strings? are they just alphanumeric? alpha only? symbols? any printable? any ascii excluding dilimeters?

Comment: Also, must a string exist? would there ever be an empty string? like stringA,"","",,"",""

Comment: @QuinnRoundy Each string has alphanumeric characters including spaces. All characters are printable. All are ASCII. The delimiter is ",". String F as mentioned above additionally has commas within itself. Yes a string must exist and cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [ ] expression only defines a class of characters. If you don't specify a quantifier, it means: Precisely one occurrences of a character of the defined class. Therefore, your expression presumably has to look like this:

```
(([^ ]*),(\"[^\"]*\"),(\"[^\"]*\"),([^ ]*),(\"[^\"]*\"),(\"[^\"]*\"))
```

Comment: Read the comments, this almost works, but there was some extra requirements mentioned.

Comment: @rplantiko So when we specify [^\"] it means that the first character has to be " ?

Comment: That's what they said, and that they can't be empty strings

Comment: @Karan, Here ^ does not act as anchor, i.e, it does not specify the first character. It says exclude the class of characters delimited by [ and ].

Comment: So i tried the above and it does parse the csv. However the columns appear shifted backward by one i.e. when i query for the second column like select col2 from tableName, it outputs the previous i.e. the first column.

Comment: Also when i do a select * from tableName limit 1, the column values appear repeated (starting from the first column) after the last column. Is this got something to do with * in the regex?

Comment: It is because of the outermost pair of braces. If you remove them ,  values won't repeat.

Comment: @Karan You will need at least one character of the given character classes, especially for the patterns which are not surrounded by ". For this, use the quantifier + instead of * (* means: 0 or more occurrences, + means: 1 or more occurences of the preceding character or character class).

Comment: So something like (([^ ]+),(\"[^\"]*\"),(\"[^\"]*\"),([^ ]+),(\"[^\"]*\"),(\"[^\"]*\"))

Comment: I am observing weird behavior with the above regex. All strings become part of the first column and then the columns have values starting from the second string i.e. stringB. I think the first regex ([^ ]+) is matching all the strings.

Comment: @Karan The first subgroup tries to eat up the maximum set of non-blank characters it can find (+ and * are "greedy"), but then usually it should give back characters successively if the rest of the regex doesn't match (which is the case here, the commas wouldn't match if the first subgroup eats it all). Anyway: try excluding the "," in the character classes of the subgroups which are not enclosed by quote signs, so `([^ ,]+)` instead of `([^ ]+)`.

Comment: @rplantiko Thanks for the reply. Just removing the enclosing set of () worked! Accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following regex should match your pattern given the criteria.

(([^\"]+),(\"[^\"]+\"),(\"[^\"]+\"),([^\"]+),(\"[^\"]+\"),(\"[^\"]+\"))

or as mentioned, depending on language requirements (I'm not familiar with hive) you may not need to escape the quotes inside the brackets:

(([^"]+),(\"[^"]+\"),(\"[^"]+\"),([^"]+),(\"[^"]+\"),(\"[^"]+\"))

Using + matches at least the presence, * doesn't require a match.

http://regexr.com/3be3i

Comment: This could be written with half the pieces, but this should be easily readable if you are familiar with regex. Feel free to let me know if I missed somethign.

Answer (score 0):

The backslashes may not be necessary depending upon where this regex is used. Hive may need them, python does not.
The outermost braces are acting as another capture group and  are causing to match the whole string again.

```
>>> input = 'stringA,"stringB","stringC",stringD,"stringE","stringF"'
>>> print (input)
stringA,"stringB","stringC",stringD,"stringE","stringF"


>>> p = re.compile( '(([^"]+),(\"[^"]+"),(\"[^"]+"),([^"]+),(\"[^\"]+"),(\"[^"]+"))' )

>>> p.findall(input)
[('stringA,"stringB","stringC",stringD,"stringE","stringF"', 'stringA', '"stringB"', '"stringC"', 'stringD', '"stringE"', '"stringF"')]



>>> p = re.compile( '([^"]+),("[^"]+"),("[^"]+"),([^"]+),("[^"]+"),("[^"]+")' )
>>> p.findall(input)
[('stringA', '"stringB"', '"stringC"', 'stringD', '"stringE"', '"stringF"')]
>>>
```